# Searching for obstacles in list of lists?

Tags: python, list, character, continue

I'm writing a function that when given a list of lists it can determine if a specific first character is followed by a specific second character (either once or repeated) or is followed by another random string. When another random string is present the function should return False but when no random string is present the function should return True.

Basically if any other character other then `.` comes after `B` in its current list or any following lists then it should return False but if only `.` is present then it should return True.

For example, if the first character was `B` and the second character was `.` and the list of lists was `[['.','.','B','.'],['.','.','.','.']]` then it should return `True` but if the list of lists was `[['a','c','B','r'],['.','s','g','h']]` it should return `False` since a series of random strings follows `B`.

Any tips or help would be appreciated this is the code I have so far:

```
def free_of_obstacles(lst):
    A = 'B'
    B = '.'
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
            if A in v:
                continue
            if B in v:
                continue
                return True
            else: 
                return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join all the chars in each list and join all the joined strings into a single string and then apply a regex to check if there is a match or not:

```
>>> lst=[['.','.','B','.'],['.','.','.','.']]
>>> import re
>>> bool(re.search(r'B(\.+)$', ''.join(''.join(i) for i in lst)))
True
>>> lst=[['a','c','B','r'],['.','s','g','h']]
>>> bool(re.search(r'B(\.+)$', ''.join(''.join(i) for i in lst)))
False
>>>
```

**EDIT 1 ---->** Above solution as a function returning True or False:

```
>>> import re
>>> def free_of_obstacles(lst):
...     return bool(re.search(r'B(\.+)$', ''.join(''.join(i) for i in lst)))
... 
>>> lst=[['a','c','B','r'],['.','s','g','h']]
>>> free_of_obstacles(lst)
False
>>> lst=[['.','.','B','.'],['.','.','.','.']]
>>> free_of_obstacles(lst)
True
```

Without using any imported modules:

Sample run 1

```
>>> lst=[['.','.','B','.'],['.','.','.','.']]
>>> newlst=[j for i in lst for j in i]
>>> newlst=newlst[newlst.index('B')+1:]
>>> newlst
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
>>> list(map(lambda x:x=='.', newlst))
[True, True, True, True, True]
>>> all(list(map(lambda x:x=='.', newlst)))
True
```

Sample run 2

```
>>> lst=[['a','c','B','r'],['.','s','g','h']]
>>> newlst=[j for i in lst for j in i]
>>> newlst=newlst[newlst.index('B')+1:]
>>> newlst
['r', '.', 's', 'g', 'h']
>>> list(map(lambda x:x=='.', newlst))
[False, True, False, False, False]
>>> all(list(map(lambda x:x=='.', newlst)))
False
```

**EDIT 2 ---->** Above solution as a function returning True or False:

```
>>> def free_of_obstacles(lst):
...     newlst=[j for i in lst for j in i]
...     newlst=newlst[newlst.index('B')+1:]
...     return all(list(map(lambda x:x=='.', newlst)))
... 
>>> lst=[['.','.','B','.'],['.','.','.','.']]
>>> free_of_obstacles(lst)
True
>>> lst=[['a','c','B','r'],['.','s','g','h']]
>>> free_of_obstacles(lst)
False
>>>
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting a NameError that "re is not defined" when I run the test cases not sure what isnt working

Comment: @warrior4223 ohh sorry .. you will have to import the re module like this: `import re`

Comment: Sorry I know this is a lot to ask but is there a way to accomplish this without importing a module? I will give you best answer either way since your code works

Comment: Thank you for all the help this has definitely put me in the right direction. Do you know how would I have this function return True if no random characters follow B and False if random characters follow B?

Comment: @warrior4223 isn't that what you asked for? Can you edit or post a new question with sample input and desired output?

Comment: @warrior4223 you can put all the statements in a function and return a True or False accordingly, edited the answer with function implementation

Comment: thanks a lot for all the advice you've been a huge help